# Error reading View in PlayFab Shared Database: "Object 'REPORT_PRIMARY.PUBLIC.ACCOUNT_MAPPER' does not exist or not authorized."

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a Snowflake database that connects to a Shared View from PlayFab (for game events etc.) Stored procedures run daily via scheduled tasks to copy the latest data from the view into our own 'local' Snowflake table. It's been working fine, but today we're getting the following error trying to read from the PlayFab View:

Error: 100183: SQL compilation error: Failure during expansion of view 'PLAYFAB_ARCHIVE_SHARED': SQL compilation error: Object 'REPORT_PRIMARY.PUBLIC.ACCOUNT_MAPPER' does not exist or not authorized.

I can't find any mention of the error number or REPORT_PRIMARY.PUBLIC.ACCOUNT_MAPPER in the documentation. I believe error 100183 relates to a problem in a stored procedure, but I don't think it's my procedure, since I get the same error running a simple query from the PLAYFAB_ARCHIVE_SHARED view manually. I've checked the data from the PlayFab side, and it exists there. I'm not really sure whether the problem is Snowflake or PlayFab, but because of the error code, I suspect Snowflake.

I'm trying to get a direct support answer, but that doesn't seem to be happening for some reason. Anybody experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlayFab had mistakenly removed access to the view. Snowflake support confirmed that they could not find the view REPORT_PRIMARY.PUBLIC.ACCOUNT_MAPPER. After contacting PlayFab support, they re-enabled the shared view and Snowflake access is now working again.

Answer (score 0):

In past I have faced similar error on view, Its because of the access could you run grant access on the stored procedure to your role.

Comment: The role has full access to the stored procedure, and it's been working for months. I think the problem is happening before my stored procedure is run, because just a manual query to the PlayFab shared view shows the same error, and that view is showing 0 records, 0 bytes when I hover over it in worksheet.

Comment: Can PlayFab confirm the view is still shared? Or recreate it?

Comment: @pat Russell If its view it won't show the row count or size even though you have records.

Comment: @SuzyLockwood Good call - took a while, but it turned out that PlayFab had mistakenly removed access to the view. Snowflake support confirmed that they could not find the view REPORT_PRIMARY.PUBLIC.ACCOUNT_MAPPER.

Comment: Thanks @PatRussell . Good to know the resolution.